# Simulating red-green color-blindness (browser extension or other)

Tags: browser, colors, accessibility

I'd like to be able to occasionally set a browser window (or the whole browser, or failing that, all of XP) to simulate being viewed by someone who is color blind. The particular effect I'm interested in is as simple as switching off all red. Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: By the way, on a Linux desktop with Compiz that IS possible. You can apply various color filters to whole screen or specific windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a web site that offers a simulation of different types of colorblindness, red-green amongst them: [colorfilter.wickline.org](http://colorfilter.wickline.org/)

Comment: That's really useful. It was interesting to see that part of the StackExchange logo text (upper left of the page) disappeared. I never thought of grey containing colours that would present problems to the colourblind. I wonder how exact a simulation it is.

Comment: There once was a discussion in the de.comm.infosystems.www.authoring.misc newsgroup (can't find it right now) where several affected participants said that, while every case of colorblindness is different, it's important to get good contrast in these demos. IIRC, they said the demos were pretty good.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I note that it doesn't simply drop the red, but seems to rebalance the colourspace into an opposition between blue and yellow, rather than leaving it as just blue and green.